# How to preserve iTerm folder location between sessions?

Tags: location, iterm2, iterm

I'm using iTerm 2, and each time I exit and launch it again it doesn't save the folder location I was working on.

This is really annoying to have to retype each time the previous location I was working on, event more when there were multiple tabs opened...

Is there a way so that iTerm automatically save the folder path for each tab when I exit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTerm 2.9.x (currently beta) and above support restoring sessions like the default Terminal.app in OS-X.

http://iterm2.com/downloads.html

[image]

https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3717#note_1733467

Comment: Seems like this beta version adds this functionality. Too bad they didn't implement it sooner because it is really useful

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, make sure to uncheck "Close windows when quitting app" in the System Preferences/General tab (note this is in the System Preferences, not in the iTerm2 preferences).

Also set the following iTerm2 settings in the iTerm2 preferences:

- General tab: select Use System Window Restoration Setting
- General tab: uncheck Open profiles Window
- General tab: uncheck Confirm closing multiple sessions
- General tab: Confirm "Quit iTerm2 (⌘Q)" command
- Advanced tab: Restore Window contents at startup = Yes